# Counted value grouped by date range

Tags: mysql, group-by

From a Call Detail Record (CDR) table, I need to compute the maximum channels that have been simultaneously busy in a specified time range. The table has one column for the end of the call time and another column for the call duration.

```
CallID  DateTime              Duration
  1     2014-04-28 11:37:54         35
  2     2014-04-28 11:37:53         82
  3     2014-04-28 11:37:42         53
  4     2014-04-28 11:37:37        159
  5     2014-04-28 11:37:13         49
  6     2014-04-28 11:37:02        267
  7     2014-04-28 11:37:00        267
  8     2014-04-28 11:36:54         49
  9     2014-04-28 11:36:20        266
```

I would need a report for getting a response like this (time range in hours for example):

```
DateRange                NumBusyChannels
2014-04-28 11:00-12:00                 9
2014-04-28 10:00-11:00                 5
```

EDIT: Sample table to test Miky response.

```
CallID  DateTime             Duration
   014  2013-07-23 08:42:42        3
   015  2013-07-23 08:42:42        3
   019  2013-07-23 08:42:42        3
   012  2013-07-23 08:10:00        3
   013  2013-07-23 08:10:00        3
   016  2013-07-23 08:10:00        3
   017  2013-07-23 08:10:00        3
   018  2013-07-23 08:10:00        3
```

Comment: could u please explain how the calculation is done ? its not clear from the question.

Comment: i don't get it. Duration is (presumably) in seconds so there were no busy channels from 10-11 !?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: yeah right, sample table does not have records for 10-11, but you get the idea xD

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Call Id 9 ended at 11:36:20 and was active for 266 seconds, therefore it started at 11:31:54. Call Id 8 ended at 11:36:54 and was active for 49 seconds, therefore it started at 11:36:05; so both calls would count as busy for a time range of 11:30-12:00 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might start with a query like this which should give you the number of overlapping calls for each call.

```
SELECT COuter.*,
       COALESCE(COverlap.Cnt,0) as NumChannelsInUse
  FROM Cdr COuter
  LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT C1.CallId,
     COUNT(*) as Cnt
    FROM Cdr C1
    INNER JOIN Cdr C2
       ON (C2.DateTime >= C1.DateTime 
              AND 
           C2.DateTime <= DATE_ADD(C1.DateTime, INTERVAL C1.Duration SECOND))
           OR
          (DATE_ADD(C2.DateTime, INTERVAL C2.Duration SECOND) >= C1.DateTime 
              AND 
           DATE_ADD(C2.DateTime, INTERVAL C2.Duration SECOND)  <= DATE_ADD(C1.DateTime, INTERVAL C1.Duration SECOND))
           OR
          (C1.DateTime >= C2.DateTime 
              AND 
           C1.DateTime <= DATE_ADD(C2.DateTime, INTERVAL C2.Duration SECOND) )
           OR
          (DATE_ADD(C1.DateTime, INTERVAL C1.Duration SECOND) >= C2.DateTime 
              AND 
           DATE_ADD(C1.DateTime, INTERVAL C1.Duration SECOND) < DATE_ADD(C2.DateTime, INTERVAL C2.Duration SECOND))
    GROUP BY C1.CallId) COverlap
  ON COuter.CallId = COverlap.CallId
```

You would then have to further manipulate the query to partition the results by hour and then to select the maximum for each hour..

Comment: Thank you Miky, I have edited my question to include a sample data where your query generates a wrong response for some records. Calls with Ids 012,013 and 016-018 have 5 channels busy instead of 8 as the query yields.